# How to create std::string wrapper that would keep ptr to std::string and ptr to special class function from class that created that wrapper instance?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, boost, heap-memory

I have a class. It has a function `void delete_ptr(void *);` and `void push_into(std::set<my_string> ** pps);`. I have 10 instances of this class. Each one is allocated on difrent heap. I have my programm in the main heap, same where my map is. I want to call each of my class instances `push_into` with my map from main. each of push_into will call `(**pps).insert(std::string("Hello str"));` or `(**pps).insert("Hello char");`. How to create such `my_string` class that would keep `**std::string` in it and also `ptr` to `delete_ptr` of class that creates `my_string` class instance?

Main objectives I wonder about are:

- how to create its constructor to make it keep pointers to string and delete_ptr of instance that created it?

Comment: You probably want to look at allocators. The approach is different but more scalable than what you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boost::shared_ptr` with [custom deallocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors). Provide your `delete_ptr` as a custom deallocator using `boost::bind`

Comment: is it possible to make my_string at least try to get ptr to `delete_ptr` of its creator?

Comment: do you need `delete_ptr` to delete `my_string`? `shared_ptr` will handle this for you. Just store `boost::shared_ptr<std::string>` in your `set`s, provide custom comparator for them and provide pointer to your `delete_ptr` on construction. Please comment if you need an example, I'll post it tomorrow, now I need to go home

Comment: my main point was to hide from some API user that he sends anething besides string into set...)

Comment: @myWallJSON: In this case as Dietmar recommended, allocator can be the best approach.